# Value change when converting a long to a double and back

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

given the following code:

```
long l = 1234567890123;
double d = (double) l;
```

is the following expression guaranteed to be true?

```
l == (long) d
```

I should think no, because as numbers get larger, the gaps between two doubles grow beyond 1 and therefore the conversion back yields a different long value. In case the conversion does not take the value that's greater than the long value, this might also happen earlier.

Is there a definitive answer to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, absolutely not. There are plenty of `long` values which aren't exactly representable by `double`. In fact, that *has* to be the case, given that both types are represented in 64 bits, and there are obviously plenty of `double` values which aren't representable in `long` (e.g. 0.5)

Simple example (Java and then C#):

```
// Java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = Long.MAX_VALUE - 1;
        double d = x;
        long y = (long) d;
        System.out.println(x == y);
    }
}

// C#
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long x = long.MaxValue;
        double d = x;
        long y = (long) d;
        Console.WriteLine(x == y);
    }
}
```

I observed something *really strange* when doing this though... in C#, `long.MaxValue` "worked" in terms of printing False... whereas in Java, I had to use `Long.MAX_VALUE - 1`. My guess is that this is due to some inlining and 80-bit floating point operations in some cases... but it's still odd :)

Comment: The fun part here is the fact that I had asked this for the Java platform. But as I do expect the behaviour to be the same on both platforms, it remains somewhat valid. :)

Comment: @Mathias: Whoops, sorry. I'll write the equivalent Java code.

Comment: Java converts (on my 32bit machine) Long.MAX_VALUE=9223372036854775807 to 0x1.0p63 (rounding up), which in turn is converted to Long.MAX_VALUE like any other double that is too large to fit in a long.

Comment: @hd42: Hmm... I may get round to investigating the difference at some point. Just not now :)

Comment: According to the [VMSpec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#33499) the value must be rounded to nearest where even is used in case of a tie. No idea how it goes in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this as there are a finite number of long values.

```
for (long l = Long.MIN_VALUE; l<Long.MAX_VALUE; l++)
{
  double d = (double) l;
  if (l == (long)d)
  {
    System.out.println("long " + l + " fails test");
  }
}
```

Doesn't take many iterations to prove that;

l = -9223372036854775805
d = -9.223372036854776E18
(long)d = -9223372036854775808

Comment: Well, I think it would be interesting to try at which earliest point this does happen when starting to count from 0 as the problem is equal for large numbers regardless of their sign.

Answer (score 1):

My code started with 0 and incremented by 100,000,000. The smallest number that failed the test was found to be 2,305,843,009,300,000,000 (19 digits). So, any positive long less than 2,305,843,009,200,000,000 is representable exactly by doubles. In particular, 18-digit longs are also representable exactly by doubles.

By the way, the reason I was interested in this question is that I wondered if I can use doubles to represent timestamps (in milliseconds). Since current timestamps are on the order of 13 digits (and it will take for them rather long time to get to 18 digits), I'll do that.